# How to access javascript function in the eval() scope

Tags: javascript, eval

I use `eval()` to execute javascript that is returned by an ajax request from the server. However, I cant call a function that was created with eval() and got a `ReferenceError: function is not defined`.

Is it something normal that functions inside a javascript that was executed with eval() cannot be accessed? Is there a way to access such functions?

**I think this simple jsFiddle illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/M2GLs/**

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle or sample code for this, I'm having difficultly understanding the problem. Thanks,

Comment: To answer your last question: every function can be accessed ;)

Comment: An ajax call within an eval of something returned from an ajax call? I'd seriously consider rethinking your architecture.

Comment: https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#core.eval

Comment: @torazaburo well, its a full asynchrous app :P but your comment is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The created function isn't in the correct scope. So your onclick can't 'see' it. Use

```
window.addFeatureToTable = function() { 
    // definition
}
```

to force it in the window-scope.

Working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2GLs/1/)

To answer your question in the comment:

What you actualy have is something like this code:

```
function a()
{
    function b(where) {
        alert('b can be called inside a, but not outside, we are now ' + where);
    }
    b('inside');
}

a();
b('outside');
```

`b` is defined in the scope of `a`, and can only be accessed within this scope ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sm3w5/)). In your case the function-definition is within an eval, but the same rule aplies there. In that case within the scope of `function(r)`. You can't access the scope of this function from within the `a.onclick`, so you have to change the function-definition. Alternatively you can bind the on-click just after the eval ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2GLs/3/)), since it is then still in scope:

```
js = "function someFunction() { alert('function called') }"
eval(js)
document.getElementById('myA').onclick = someFunction;
```

Comment: Thats the solution, can you elaborate why the function is not in the correct scope, in what scope is it? Is it possible to call the function specifying the right scope instead?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar - I answered your question with an edit (couldn't fit in a comment ;) )